# Delphi - Paint text so it would not disappear after repainting the image under it

Tags: delphi, canvas, delphi-7, paint

How should I paint text on canvas so that the text won't disappear after repaint/update/refresh without repainting it again and again? Like it was painted as image and not temporarily painted.

Comment: It depends on what canvas you're painting to. If you're working with a custom control, there's one way to go. But if you're working with something like your form's canvas, then it's a different story.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are talking about, for example, a `TPaintBox` control or something similar, then there is no persistent canvas to paint on. The system simply is not designed that way and the VCL controls reflect the underlying Windows framework.

The normal approach is as follows:

1. Paint first to an offscreen bitmap.
2. When the system asks for a repaint, draw the offscreen bitmap onto the screen canvas.

There are a variety of reasons that may lead you to this approach. Often performance is a factor. It may be expensive to paint and caching the image can help. Sometimes the information required in order to paint may be transient and again caching the output may be a solution.

Answer (score 4):

You can't. Painting only shows the image on the screen once; if you want it to persist then you *must* repaint it each time the OS requests it.

Answer (score 0):

Use a TLabel (or some derivative) and place it over the canvas. The TLabel will redraw itself whenever necessary.

Comment: Asker is referring to drawing text to a TCanvas. There must be a feasible reason why they're using the canvas to draw their text instead of a label.

Answer (score 0):

You need to only draw when the system says you should. There's two things to know about with this subject...

**Cache**

You can also implement your own cache system. This can get a little tricky when working with many layers. You may have a particular area which is expected to change at a high rate. And then the background presumably isn't going to be changed unless it's been resized, or a color has changed, etc. Such as a needle moving on top of some photo. Just maintain two different image objects in the background and combine them, making sure at least the one(s) on top are transparent.

You can also tell Windows when your control's cache is invalidated (next subject...) by using the `Invalidate` command. This will tell Windows that something in your control has changed to the point where you need to redraw everything. Windows will then decide when it's ready to actually tell your control to be painted again by calling a `Paint` procedure.

**System Paint**

As David mentions in his answer, if you're working with a control, then you should repaint your background when the system says you should. This is accomplished by inheriting the `Paint` procedure from the `TGraphicControl` or the `TCustomControl` (and some others). This procedure is called every time the system says you need to refresh your control's contents. It's the system's way of telling you when your cache is invalidated.

```
procedure Paint; override;
...
procedure TMyCustomControl.Paint;
begin
  DoSomeDrawingOnCanvas;
end;
```

On the other hand, you can tell Windows whenever you want it to call this `Paint` procedure too...

```
procedure TMyCustomControl.SetWidth(const Value: Integer);
begin
  if Value <> FWidth then begin //Just a common check for performance reasons
    FWidth:= Value;
    Invalidate; //This tells Windows that you want to repaint your control
  end;
end;
```